# My app doesn't detect layout-land folder with horizontal orientation screen

Tags: android, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

I have created a layout-land folder where I have saved the designs of my specific layouts for the landscape version.... The problem is that when I install the application on my phone, when I rotate the screen, it continues to show me the same layouts as for the portrait version, as if it did not recognize the designs in the layout-land folder....

I would also like to say that I have verified that my phone does detect changes in screen orientation, when the screen is vertical the app shows a toast that says "Portrait" while when it is horizontal it shows a "Landscape" toast, which means my phone detects the orientation changes but nevertheless in landscape it does not apply the designs from my layout-land folder, and that is what has me puzzled... do you know if there is something that I am missing? Maybe some line of code in the activity tag of my Manifest.xml? Or what could I be missing...?

I want to get a responsive design of my app for screen orientation changes.

Comment: Check your manifest for a few things-  1)Do you lock the screen orientation?  If so, remove that.  2)Do you declare a configChanges="orientationChange" in your manifest?  If so, remove that (it causes the OS to call a function on your Activity rather than restart it on orientation changes).

Comment: in my activity tag I have the following line.................                                                 
 android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"................ maybe something is missing, I don't know.

Comment: Remove that.  What that does is stop your activity from being restarted on orientation changes.  If it doesn't restart, then onCreate isn't called and you don't recreate a new UI based on the appropriate layout.  That line stops the entire mechanism you want to use.

Comment: Okay, I've already removed that line. But the problem remains there. When I turn the screen to landscape orientation, it does not take the layouts from the layout-land folder, which are the ones it should show.

Answer (score 0):

My onCreate method in MainActivity is:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

So I understand that when starting the activity it will always call the layout corresponding to the layout folder, instead of showing the one from the layout-land folder. The issue is that I get an error when I try to put the following line:

setContentView(R.layout-land.activity_main).

Or by setting R.layout.activity_main would it be possible to also execute the layout of the layout-land folder, or that of other folders?

And also comment that I also have four other folders for the different screen sizes: layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp. layout-sw720dp.

Comment: This looks like a follow-on question to your original question.  Since there are no other answers to your question, you should edit the original question to include the follow-up, or create a new question. Thanks!